# Wrap Windows cmd in Python with extra quotes

Tags: python

I want to execute this cmd:

```
WMIC Printer Where "Name Like '%name%'" Delete
```

in Python:

```
import os
os.system('cmd /k "WMIC Printer Where "Name Like '%name%'" Delete"')
```

But I get this traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\kvanimpe\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2022.1\scratches\scratch_9.py", line 2, in 
> os.system('cmd /k "WMIC Printer Where "Name Like '%name%'" Delete"')
> NameError: name 'name' is not defined

How can I define 'name' as a part of a normal Windows command?

Comment: You need to escape the quotes to keep them in the string content rather than being interpreted as string delimiters: `'%name%'` >> `\'%name%\'`

Comment: set name=whatever

Answer (score 2):

For your case you could do:

```
os.system('cmd /k "WMIC Printer Where "Name Like \'%name%\'" Delete"')
```

The backslash works with other things too such as:

```
print("example\\path\\for\\example or even double \"quotes\"")
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

When I'm too lazy to figure out the backslashes, this is what I do, raw strings and triple start/end quotes:

```
>>> print(r'''cmd /k "WMIC Printer Where "Name Like '%name%'" Delete"''')
cmd /k "WMIC Printer Where "Name Like '%name%'" Delete"

>>> print(r'''example\path\for\example or even double "quotes"''')
example\path\for\example or even double "quotes"
```

These can be mixed with f-strings as well:

```
>>> name = 'bob'
>>> print(rf'''cmd /k "WMIC Printer Where "Name Like '%{name}%'" Delete"''')
cmd /k "WMIC Printer Where "Name Like '%bob%'" Delete"
```